# How to make a clickable Auto-Scroll in iOS 5,6?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, autoscroll

My application requires an autoscroll where titles of different articles scroll. And when I click on any on of the article, the details of that particular article should shows.

I have tried a lot of things, and quite a few approaches. None seems to working perfectly. The approach with most promise has been where I use the autoscroll from [AutoScrollLabel](https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel)

And also for clickable text on UI-Label [RichUILabels](http://locassa.com/interactive-rich-text-uilabel/)

A small issue that I am facing with this currently is that the text that is shown as clickable is only a word a not the whole sentence. I could add specific separators between these Article-Titles if that helps. But even still I am not sure about how to make the complete sentence as the highlighted text.

Is there a simpler approach for doing this?

1. Feel free to suggest me a completely new approach.
2. Or if this could be done by simply using multiple AutoScrollLabels

Pls let me know if you need any more information regarding this.

Comment: you can try by integrating following solutions 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12856174/1228669
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3694455/1228669

Basically the idea is create a infinite scroll view with buttons and scroll it using timer

Comment: Thanks.. This looks interesting. It is a sort of workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate UIButtons in UIScrollView dynamically and assign a target to it for redirecting to next screen. see the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //[myMapView addAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)];

    int y=10;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, y, 280, 40);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag=i;
        [button setTitle:(NSString *)@"new button" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myScroll addSubview:button];

        y+=45;
    }
}
```

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender

```
{
    // code for redirecting to another view
   // use button tag property for identifying perticular record

}
```

you can assign the title of articles to button text. store the articles data in array and assign it in the following manner.

```
[button setTitle:(NSString *)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Okay. Hmm..But I think this would not get me an auto-scroll?

Comment: Auto Scroll as in the text on the label should scroll automatically, like a marquee.

Answer (score 0):

hi please try this code:

```
float alph = 0.7;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    glowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    NSString *string = @"some text";
    glowLabel.text = string;
    glowLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:glowLabel];
    glowLabel.alpha = alph;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4
                                   target:self
                                   selector:@selector(glowMarquee)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];
}

-(void)glowMarquee {
    alph = (alph == 1) ? 0.7 : 1; // Switch value of alph
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"alpha" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];        
    glowLabel.alpha = alph;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Use this code for generating label while creating list of articles.
hope this will help you.