# Is it possible to have a UITextView scroll through text automatically, and repeatedly in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, uitextview

Is it possible to have a UITextView scroll through text automatically, and repeatedly? Like, I have a UITextView, and the text just scrolls, and scrolls, and when it has reached the end, repeats itself, over and over, without the user having to scroll?

Comment: Yes.  UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: Yes - take a look at this SO response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694411/how-to-auto-scroll-uiscrollview-using-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
        {    
          h=0;   // add the variable int h to your interface
            myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 
                                                           target:self 
                                                          selector:@selector(scrollPosition) 
                                                           userInfo:nil 
                                                           repeats:YES]; 
        }

- (void) scrollPosition {
                   h += 50; // add the variable int h to your interface
                //you must add the textview delegate to file's owner
                 [self.textview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, h) animated:YES];  

                   }

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
                        {
                 float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
                 float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
                 float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
                    //  at the end of scrollview
                if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight)
                            {
                //you must add the textview delegate to file's owner
                [self.textview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES]; 
                [myTimer invalidate];
                myTimer = nil;
                h=0;
                myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 
                                                               target:self 
                                                              selector:@selector(scrollPosition) 
                                                               userInfo:nil 
                                                               repeats:YES]; 
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: "Use of undeclared identifier self"? @Chandu kumar.Alasyam

Comment: Hi @TonyStark where you are adding the "mytimer".you must add the "mytimer"with in the method like Viewdidload or your method...i am modifying the code plz check once it is working fine