# How can I display an image that scrolls automatically in the background of my uiviewcontroller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In my swift app I have a `UIViewController` with some buttons and labels. I thought it would be cool to have an image in the background that scrolls (slides) slowly from right to left automatically. I manage to put in the background `UIImageView` and assigned constraints so that it covers the full panel, but I'm not sure how can I scroll the photo in it.

I have a png file in the proportion of `21:9` - is it possible to make it scroll then?

Comment: For how long do you intend to make the image slide?

Comment: if possible - indefinitely, I mean when this picture reaches the end - I thought about putting the same photo there and continue scrolling, so the user won't see any empty space... If that's not possible then until it's the end of the photo then.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift**

```
   func viewDidLoad(){
     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func moveToNextImage (){
            let imgsCount:CGFloat = CGFloat(images.count)
            let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.imageScrollView.frame.width
            let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * imgsCount
            let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.x

            var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth

            if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth{
                slideToX = 0
            }
            let currentPage:CGFloat = slideToX / pageWidth
            // Change the indicator
            self.pageController.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
            self.imageScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x:slideToX, y:0, width:pageWidth, height:self.imageScrollView.frame.height), animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use uiview animations for this

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.4,
    options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
      // scroll automatically using scroll view method (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated.Keep animated NO**strong text**.you can scroll horizontally or vertically using offset.

    }, completion: nil)
```

You can check out other animation options.I haven't tried animating scroll before.
Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in a scrollview and keep changing the content offset of the scrollview in an NSTimer. Check this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694455/6080920

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another `UIImageView` and constrain it to your original `UIImageView` by constraining the new view's leading anchor to the old view's trailing anchor.
2. Create an `IBOutlet` for the `leading` anchor constraint for the original `UIImageView`.
3. Set the image of the new imageView to be the same as in the original one.

Note:
*For the best effect, you should be using a seamless tileable image.*

Call `slideImage()` from your `viewDidAppear(_:)`

```
@IBOutlet var backgroundImageConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

func slideImage(){

    // Changes constant to be equal to the image width,
    // this will move the image off-screen on the left-hand side.
    backgroundImageConstraint.constant = backgroundImage.frame.width

    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .Repeat], animations: {
        // Animates the constant change
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: {
            done in

            // Resets the image view back to its original position before starting a new round of the animation
            self.backgroundImageConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    })
}
```

Edit:

Example project can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73435854296769273710)

Comment: Thanks, so tell me - this `IBOutlet` for backgroundImage is assigned to the first or the 2nd image? And what about the other one then?

Comment: The outlet is for the first UIImageView, you don't need an outlet for the other one. This is because it's constrained to the first view that makes it automatically hang onto tje first view.

Comment: And one more question - speaking about point no `2` - IBOutlet for the `leading` anchor - is it the outlet to just created (in point no `1`) constraint? or to some other one?

Comment: It's the leading anchor constraint for the first UIImaheView; in other words, the original one :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience! So currently my storyboard for that looks as follows http://imgur.com/ZPLK5Xd and I have 2 outlets - `backgroundImage` connected to the `Background Image` and `backgroundImageConstraint` connected to `Background Image.leading = leading Margin - 20`. However now my photo goes to the right (and doesn't keep the aspect ratio, with every pixel to the right it expands) and then resets... Am I missing something here? :(

Comment: (btw. my photo has the aspect ratio of 21:9 so I'm not sure if that causes the problems, I guess I should set up somehow the aspect ratio in the code too)

Comment: Select the constraint, look in one of the drop downs and uncheck the relative to margins. Also click on the reverse first and secomd view.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried it and it almost works, but there are still some issues and I thought I won't bother you with questions any more, however - if you have time - is there any way you could post somewhere maybe a sandboxed code for that? I think if I go through it live in xcode then everything would be super clear to me...

Comment: Sure, the first thing tomorrow morning :)

Comment: example project aint there :( anymore

Answer (score 0):

By using this 3rd party we can do that

https://github.com/guowilling/SRInfiniteCarouselView

We can add a view in that we can just pass these line of code.

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *demoView;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  SRInfiniteCarouselView *imageCarouselView = [SRInfiniteCarouselView sr_carouselViewWithImageArrary:serviceImgArray describeArray:nil placeholderImage:nil delegate:self];
        imageCarouselView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.demoView.frame.size.width, self.demoView.frame.size.height);
        imageCarouselView.timeInterval = 05.0;
        [imageCarouselView setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [imageCarouselView setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.demoView addSubview:imageCarouselView];
}
```